# Format an arbitrary date in Word

Tags: date-time, microsoft-word-2016, office-for-mac

I need to insert a specific date in Word and have it formatted with the name of the day in the form "Name of the Day, DD.MM.YYYY". If I change the date the name of the day would be change accordingly. I know how to do that in excel, but is it possible in Word, maybe with a field?

An example: say I want to insert 1st January 2020. Is it possible to write it in the field as 1/1/2020 and have it formated as "Wednesday, 1st January 2020"? And then if I change the date to 2/1/2020 it would automatically change to "Thursday, 2nd January 2020"?

**EDIT**: I use Word 2016 for Mac, if this is of any relevance.

Comment: A bit of background information: I need this for work, because I often write documents with dates in them in format "name of the day, DD.MM.YYYY" or something similar (it is in German). 

It happens all too often that I have to change the date and forget to change the name of the day. I don't want that to happen anymore (and I have to write the name of the day, I cannot simply write the date). The date I write is something like a deadline or a meeting, it has nothing to do with the print date of the document or any of the options that word offers.

Comment: Please edit in your comment into the question, or people will miss it.

Comment: The version of Word that you use certainly might be relevant.  In fact, it would be good if you told us exactly what version you are using.  (Microsoft Office version numbers are usually years, like 2007 and 2011, but can be ‘‘365’’.)  Mention the version number in the question and add the version-specific tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, for anyone interested:

Under **Word** -> **Preferences** -> **View**, check **Show developer tab**.

While working on your document in the tab **Developer** click **Text Box**. This will add a new blank field in your document. Double-click the field and in the dialog box choose type "Date" and choose the date format you want or write it. Write the date in the field "Default date" in a usual format (for me it worked with DD/MM/YYYY but check depending on your system and language).